# How to use the value of a variable as a type hint in python

Tags: python, oop, python-typing, code-completion

How do I assign a variable value as a type hint? I have attached a sample code for what I want to achieve:

```py
class Class1:
    var1 = 1

class Class2:
    var2 = 2

class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

class ChildClass1(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(var=Class1)

    def fun(self):
        self.var.  # How to get type hint here for Class1 like it should show var1

class ChildClass2(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(var=Class2)

    def fun(self):
        self.var.  # How to get type hint here for Class2 like it should show var2
```

Edit 1: By "type hint" I mean that after typing `self.var` the intellisense of the IDE should give my recommendations like those we get when we type `str().` and then we get e.g. `strip()`.

Edit 2: @DaniilFajnberg Gave a nice solution to the problem ie Generics, but still keeping the question as active because I am looking for solutions other than Generics (I already mentioned that in a comment).

Comment: If you are looking to type a variable look at  https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html , but if you are looking at what the type is for a variable you could use `type(var)` to get the type of `var`

Comment: @AndrewRyan I looked at typing but could not find a solution which matches my requirement and I do not want to consider Generic class as it is not the right implementation in my case.

Comment: Generics **are** the solution for this. You can't assign the _"value of a variable as a type hint"_. Type annotations are for static type checkers; and those don't execute your code, they just read it. If you want that type inference, you'll have to declare it on every `ChildClass` individually, e.g.: `class ChildClass1(BaseClass):`  `var: Class1`

Comment: "[Type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-type-hint)" is already a term in Python, and it's not what you're describing here. You're talking about [completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete#In_source_code_editors) (or *suggestions*).

Comment: @wjandrea I agree with you that there is already a term called Type Hint in python, but just curious doesn't  type hints lead to completion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you specifically mentioned in the comments that you *don't* want generics, but since they **are** the textbook solution to this problem, maybe somebody else coming across this question will find this useful:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Class1:
    var1 = 1

class Class2:
    var2 = 2

class BaseClass(Generic[T]):
    var: type[T]

    def __init__(self, var: type[T]) -> None:
        self.var = var

class ChildClass1(BaseClass[Class1]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(var=Class1)

class ChildClass2(BaseClass[Class2]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(var=Class2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child1 = ChildClass1()
    child2 = ChildClass2()
    reveal_type(child1.var)  # this line is for mypy
    reveal_type(child2.var)  # this line is for mypy
```

This results in `mypy` giving the following output:

```
[...].py:35: note: Revealed type is "Type[[...].Class1]"
[...].py:36: note: Revealed type is "Type[[...].Class2]"
```

Any worthwhile IDE will give you the desired auto-suggestions with this setup.

Remember that runtime type annotations are a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Got no other approach, hence upvoting this as the accepted answer.